# search option on PHP codeigniter based website

Tags: php, codeigniter, search

I am developing news site using `php codeigniter`.It is in different languages. When a user search for any news by entering keyword, It should find news related to searched keyword.
How can I do that?
Shall I use indexing ?

Comment: What is your research on this?

Comment: I found out google custom search but it is not working for my site

Answer (score 2):

You can use Full Text Search for searching keywords in SQL database

Check this...

[Full Text Search Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142583.aspx)

Sure, You must use Indexing, Indexing will help to fetch results fast.
You can also use Inner Join, left join etc to get structured result, but I have tried this kind of search by making an SQL view.

See this is how you can make SQL view

[SQL View Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-views.htm)

It helps me to search related results fast

Comment: Thank you. where I can find information about indexing. It is very new concept for me.

Comment: Check these....www.youtube.com/watch?v=rreKY6K3S_A, http://www.interspire.com/content/2006/02/15/introduction-to-database-indexes/